# Passing border of North Macedonia as Albanian citizen with driver license as ID?

Tags: borders, macedonia, albanian-citizens

Can I pass the borders of North Macedonia as Albanian citizen with driving license as ID?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_North_Macedonia no, a driver licence is not sufficient. Albanian citizens may enter North Macedonia with a national ID card for a stay of max 90 days within 180 days.

Answer (score 5):

There are few exceptions, but most of the countries do not recognize a driving license as a valid travel document.

In case of North Macedonia, you need a valid biometric ID card or passport([source - Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=135&Itemid=437&lang=en))

Comment: Canada, Mexico, United Kingdom, Republic of Ireland, some Caribbean countries and USA are just a few I can think of that allow a driving licence (sometimes enhanced) to be used for either it's own or certain citizens.

Comment: @BritishSam any official source that those countries allow people to entry their territory only using a driving license?

Comment: Your answer is right with regards to this, I up voted it. `An Enhanced license (permit, or non-driver ID) is a New York State DMV issued document that you can use instead of a passport to return to the US by land or sea from Canada, Mexico and some countries in the Caribbean.`

https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/get-enhanced-driver-license-edl

Comment: `Most people need a valid passport to enter the Republic or Northern Ireland but there are some exceptions: • If you're a UK citizen, you can also use official photo identification.` https://www.ireland.com/en-gb/about-ireland/travel-information/visa-passport-and-embassy-information-in-ireland/

Comment: @BritishSam fair enough :)